# Mat-Table matCellDef issue with mapping model which has special character

Tags: angular, angular-material2, ng-container

The data I got from a different REST API has field names with special characters and spaces in between them.

For example, instead of passing `row.DatasetID` like this:

```xml
<ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.DatasetID}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

I would like to pass it like this:

```xml
<ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.'Dataset ID'}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

How can I format the mapping if the return proper/field name has space or special characters like "@"?

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets to the rescue:

```
{{ row['Dataset ID'] }}
```